# displaying <li> elements left and right side according to the condition

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'am trying to display messages with the help of 'li' tag line by line .The main motive is to display our messages on right side whereas others on the left side in a react Chat app
but the problems is whenever I try with float left or float right , all the elements come into the same line like this

[image: chat messages]

**My react chat styling code is this**

```
      {this.state.chats.map(chat => (<div key={chat.timestamp}>
        {this.state.user.uid === chat.uid  ?(
       <li className=" self" style={{listStyleType:"none",overflow:'hidden',marginLeft: 2 +'px',float:'right',display:'inline-block',
            backgroundColor:"whitesmoke",margin:2 + "em",padding:13+'px',width:'max-content',borderBottomLeftRadius:11+'px',
            borderBottomRightRadius:11+'px',borderTopLeftRadius:11+'px'}}>

                <div className="message text-dark">{chat.content} </div>
        </li>
            
          ):(
                <li className="other" style={{listStyleType:"none",overflow:'hidden',marginLeft: 2 +'px',float:'left',display:'inline-block',
            backgroundColor:"blanchedalmond",margin:2 + "em",padding:13+'px',width:'max-content',borderBottomLeftRadius:11+'px',
            borderBottomRightRadius:11+'px',borderTopRightRadius:11+'px'}}>
          
                 <div className="message text-dark">{chat.content}</div>
            
            </li>
            
          )}
        </div>
        ))}
```

**Edit !: after floating individual div**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.self {
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.other {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="self">message</li>
  <li class="self">message</li>
  <li class="self">message</li>
  <li class="self">message</li>
  <li class="other">message</li>
  <li class="other">message</li>
  <li class="other">message</li>
  <li class="self">message</li>
</ul>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear
Check out the clear property for floated elements.

Comment: basically the main things its doing float only but whenever i am using float the above problem arises

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox solution:**

```css
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="left">
    Others message
  </li>
  <li class="right">
    Your message
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2**

Try `<li>` take up the whole line, and put `float: left/right` to the inner `<div>`

Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/L1g6wx34/

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="left">
      Others message
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="right">
      Your message
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="right">
      Your message
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: removed float from li and tried floating div but all the element are now vertically alligned

Comment: Can you reproduce it on fiddle?

Comment: i have inserted the view of layout after trying yr code

Comment: Actually there are several ways to achieve it. Are you sure the <li> take the full width of the line? I'll give you another solution with flexbox later

Comment: yeah the li was taking the full width I was only keeping the width of background color to be max-content . btw using "clear" property it worked out for me. thnx fr yr support

Comment: @Codewizard, I have seen you accepted the clear solution. It's indeed a solution. BTW, i have update the flexbox solution, you can check if you have any interested.

Comment: yeah sure going to try that also just now

Comment: actually i remember doing it yesterday but it was not helpfull. today also same result all are comming in one line

Comment: I'm sure both methods could work. Since you have the solution already, and you don't reproduce the issue on jsfiddle or plunker.... I cannot help more with it